# sqrt() c++ and math.sqrt() python

Tags: python, c++

i am new at python and i had this precision  problem with python which i did not have before with c++, the code is
for python

```
import math


def f(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)


print((38 / (math.sqrt(38) * math.sqrt(38))))
print(38 / (f(38) * f(38)))
print(math.acos(38 / (math.sqrt(38) * math.sqrt(38))))
print(math.acos(38 / (f(38) * f(38))))
```

the result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(math.acos(38 / (math.sqrt(38) * math.sqrt(38))))
ValueError: math domain error
1.0000000000000002
1.0000000000000002
```

for c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
 double f(double x);
int main()
{
    cout <<38/(f(38)*f(38))<<endl;
    cout <<38/(sqrt(38)*sqrt(38))<<endl;
    cout <<acos(38/(f(38)*f(38)))<<endl;
    cout <<acos(38/(sqrt(38)*sqrt(38)))<<endl;
    return 0;
}
double f(double x)
{
    return sqrt(x);
}
```

the result is

```
1
1
nan
0
```

this can make crashes

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Floating point is an approximation. Roundoff errors can accumlate and the result may not be exactly `1`.

Comment: And C++ is politely rounding those numbers off to six decimal points unless you ask for more.

Comment: there are few things : sqrt()*sqrt() give you the exact value in c++ when using >> operator for cout or as an argument for acos() function, but when u use sqrt() as returning value for a function (f() in code i), u get a difference, the >> operator for cout still give the exact value (maybe the rnded one) but using the f() as a an argument for acos() give a "nan" which is an out of range error. with python using math.sqrt() or math.sqrt() as retuning value of function, u get always an out of range error. so the argument for acos() sqrt()*sqrt() in c++ not the same as math.sqrt()*math.sqrt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different programming languages may behave differently when it comes to float arithmetics. It may come to optimisations, internal implementations of functions like `acos` etc.

First, notice that in C++, `acos` returns the special value `nan` for values out of range, while in Python it throws the `ValueError` exception. You can, however, easily get the C++ behavior like this:

```py
import math

def my_acos(x):
    try:
        return math.acos(x)
    except ValueError:
        return float("nan")
```

Furthermore, you can add rounding to accept values slightly out of range. Your number has 15 zeroes after the decimal point, so let's round to 15 places (for the sake of demonstration):

```py
import math

def my_acos(x):
    try:
        return math.acos(round(x, 15))
    except ValueError:
        return float("nan")
```

With this modification, your code will produce the results you expect.

Comment: tnx, i will modify the code to much the requirements, this actually is problem with the angle between two geometric vector, if it is equal or near Pi or 0, specially with moving objects with steep time gradient , where there is a probability for this to happen. also sqrt() as a returning value of function is the same as using it directly in python, which is not the case with c++.